# NetSuite - Generating Excel with SuiteScript 2.0 keeps corrupting upon opening

Tags: excel, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Hope you can assist.

I have a scheduled script in SuiteScript 2.0, which does the following:

1) Loads a XML file from the filing cabinet (code snippet below):

```
    var fileObj = FILEMODULE.load({id: fileId });

    if (fileObj.size < 10485760){
        log.debug('units to start with', RUNTIMEMODULE.getCurrentScript().getRemainingUsage());
        log.debug('file contents', fileObj.getContents());
        return fileObj.getContents();
    }
```

This XML file is used as a template for the Excel generation.

2) Runs a saved search and calls a function inside the result loop to formulate the rows and cells:

```
    content += '<Row>'
    content +=  '<Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">' + data + '</Data></Cell>';
```

End of the loop, we close the `"<Row>"` with `"</Row>"`

3) Lastly we add the final bit of HTML code to the content string used for the content of the Excel file:

```
    content += '</Table></Worksheet></Workbook>';
```

4) Creates a file, and uploads to filing cabinet

```
     var xlsFile = FILEMODULE.create({name: 'TEST.xls', fileType: 'EXCEL', contents: base64EncodedString});

     xlsFile.folder=1173; //folder name=XML Templates
     var fileID = xlsFile.save();
```

BUT....

5) Upon opening without data, it works fine (this confirms the XML template is fine).

6) Upon opening with 2 lines of data from the search, it works fine. All 26 columns print in the cells.

7) After this, adding more than 2 lines causes a corruption error. File refuses to open.

[image]

I have used XML beautify tools online to inspect the xml code and honestly, the code of line 1 and 2, really does not look much different line 3 onwards.

Checking the excel file out on Notepad++ to inspect the xml code, all new rows register as one line (as opposed to a new line) - notice the screenshot which stops at line 169... Could this be why?

[image]

Any ideas on diagnosing this will be most appreciated.

Note: The initial template was built through creating the headings in the style/format I wanted on Excel, then saving as "XML Spreadsheet".

Answer (score 1):

we can't really see everything you're doing so debugging is tough.

One thing is you should escape all your data. So include N/xml and :

```
content +=  '<Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">' + data + '</Data></Cell>';
```

should be:

```
content +=  '<Cell ss:StyleID="s67"><Data ss:Type="String">' + xml.escape({xmlText:data}) + '</Data></Cell>';
```

You're statement about looping with a row and then  ending sounds like you may have

```
<Row><Cell/><Cell/> //not closing the row for each row of search results. 
<Row><Cell/><Cell/>
<Row><Cell/><Cell/>
...
</Row>
```

For clarity you may want to output a line feed after each row. Check the spec XML should allow only line feeds but since this is an MS format they may want CRLF instead.

so for each row:

```
content += '</Row>\n';
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what "CRLF" means please?

Comment: The loop appears to be printing the xml correctly because the first two rows successfully show on the Excel file. Its when the search is > 2 results that the whole file corrupts.

Comment: CRLF is Carriage Return/Line Feed. `\r\n` but `\n` is the standard for XML. Also I added escaping the data to the example.

Comment: Excellent @bkknights - will give this a shot.

Comment: adding \n on my code resolve my issue. Thanks @bknigts